# Should Yes/No dependent variable be categorical or continuous in model?

Tags: model, binary-data

I have a yes/no dependent that I am interested in modeling. Yes means that a bird took a seed, No means that bird did not.

Should I code it such that it is read as a categorical variable or a continuous variable?

Answer (score 3):

Yes/no is categorical.

http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/catdat.htm

> Categorical variables represent types of data which may be divided
>   into groups. Examples of categorical variables are race, sex, age
>   group, and educational level.